# Missing terms/extra commas in link-sharing prompt at bottom of unanswered questions

Tags: bug

I recently started encountering some strange formatting in the prompt to share unanswered questions. The names of the various sharing services other than email were missing, leaving an awkward string of commas. Screencap:

[image: commas]

Example posts: [post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25337731/1530508), [post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25337943/1530508)

Comment: @Antony Cross-site dupe then. Should I delete this post?

Comment: Wow, what a great feature! I have never messed with installing Adblock Plus, but if it turns off social networking on the Internet, *I must get it now*.